# Does Android app needs to request again for registration on SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE message in C2DM?

Tags: android, notifications, push

I have implemented C2DM in one of the applications and its working properly. Sometimes, what happens that when registering for C2DM the error message comes as SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Now, in C2DM docs its mentioned that the application should back off and try later. I wanted to know that whether its mobile application that should back-off and again try to register or will the server back-off and send the registration id whenever it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message means no registration id could be provided, and the solution is for your app to retry. It's recommended that when requesting a registration ID that you keep trying, because if your app doesn't have one, core features that rely on push messaging will not work.

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html I am using the code from this link. As can be seen that for retrying purpose the intent com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY is used. I do not see the retry ever occuring. So, do not receive the registrationid.

Comment: I have asked another question related to the above comment. Accepting the answer since this question seems answered. Thanks.

Comment: The question related to backoff is mentioned over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673211/handling-backoff-while-implementing-c2dm-in-android